# Values at 1 of symmetric power L-functions of Maass cusp forms

Tags: nt.number-theory, rt.representation-theory, analytic-number-theory, modular-forms, automorphic-forms

I have a blur that whether one has $L(1,\text{sym}^2f)\ll \log^A q$ for some $A>0$? Here $f$ is assumed to be a Maass cusp form of square-free level $q$. If any experts here know something about this, please share the comments. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This isn't known without recourse to the Ramanujan conjecture. The best that one can do unconditionally (so far) is $L(1,\mathrm{sym}^2 f) \ll \exp(C(\log q)^{1/2} (\log \log q)^{1/4})$ for some absolute constant $C > 0$ dependent on the spectral parameter of $f$. See Corollary 1 of "Upper Bounds on $L$-Functions at the Edge of the Critical Strip" by Xiannan Li.

Comment: @PeterHumphries  Many thanks for your comments. Much obliged!